# How to split a latex document using parts and chapters

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm trying to make a PDF document, using the book class, divided like this:

- Part: 1

  - Chapter 1
  - Chapter 2
  - Etc.
- Part: 2

  - Chapter 1
  - Chapter 2
  - Etc.

How do I do this without the break in page numbers?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. I'm using book class, and with "messing up the numbers" I mean that I don't want a break in the page numbers. So I want them to be continuously and don't start over whenever I begin a new part.

Comment: I've updated the question with this information :).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is nothing fancy about creating such a document in LaTeX. You can use either the `report` or `book` document class (or another, like [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir)). The example below uses the `book` document class.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
% Comment the following to have chapters numbered without interruption (numbering through parts)
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
%...
\chapter{Last chapter}
\part{Second part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
%...
\chapter{Last chapter}
\part{Last part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
%...
\chapter{Last chapter}
\end{document}
```

The `\tableofcontents` shows the document structure. In order to have this structure accurately represent the document contents, you need to compile your code at least twice. Similar counter-resetting functionality is provided by the [`cnhgcntr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) via `\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}`, although LaTeX provides its own `\@addtoreset{<slave>}{<master>}`. Here is some information on counter resetting: [Master and slave counters](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-addtoreset)

If you want to have the numbering continue through the parts (rather than having it numbered on a per-part basis), you can comment the 3rd line of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The "\part{}"-command and the last part with uncomment the 3rd line did the job

Comment: @Simon: I've reverted my answer to have the chapters numbered on a per-part basis, rather than displaying it with the possibility to number as such. I know it already solved your problem; I just wanted to be consistent in the presentation, as reflected in your original question.

Comment: do you know how to remove the blank page after the part?  
Right now it is:  
part 1  
blank page  
chapter 1  
part 2  
blank page  
chapter 1  

I have tried with   
\makeatletter\@openrightfalse  
\part{A}  
\@openrighttrue\makeatother  

But that didn't help.

Comment: A note for `hyperref`: `\@addtoreset` and `\counterwithin` should be used *after* `hyperref` is loaded.