# Incorrect hyperlinks when \part is used. How can I correct this?

Tags: xetex, books

I used the advice in [How to split a latex document using parts and chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35782/how-to-split-a-latex-document-using-parts-and-chapters) to section my book in to parts and chapters. However, the table of contents has links to chapter n in part 1, for chapter n in any part.

I used `\counterwithin* {chapter}{part}` to get around this. Is this the right solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `hyperref` needs unique anchor names. The anchor names are mostly using the counter values. To support non-unique counter values, package `hyperref` uses a companion form of the counter `theHcounter`, which is not used for typesetting but for the anchor names. Thus you would need, e.g.:

```
 \renewcommand*{\theHchapter}{\theHpart.\thechapter).
```

Package `hyperref` adds support for `\@addtoreset` or `\counterwithin`, but this will only work, when they are used *after* `hyperref` is loaded.

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{One}\label{part:one}
\chapter{First}\label{chapter:first}
\part{Two}\label{part:two}
\chapter{Second}\label{chapter:second}
\end{document}
```